# Different TargetDir for each package with Qt Installer Framework

Tags: qt, qt-installer

Is it possible with the [Qt Installer Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/index.html) to create an installer with multiple packages, each of which has a different `TargetDir` (i.e. destination)?

For example, I want an installer that installs an SDK to `/Library/Frameworks` and a demo app to `/Applications`? Only the `/Applications` path needs to be user-editable.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there is an example for exactly this case:

http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/qt-installer-framework-modifyextract-example.html

Basically you create a script for the component that overrides the un-archiving operation:

```
Component.prototype.createOperationsForArchive = function(archive)
{
    component.addOperation("Extract", archive, "/Library/Frameworks");
}
```